# webkit-transform problems in chrome 14

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, transform

Running 14.0.835.202 m (Windows)

Animations using -webkit-transform doesn't work (for me) in Chrome anymore.

I did some HTML5 projects earlier this year, always testing in Chrome and Safari. When I check them now, a lot of animations does not work in Chrome (which has been updated several times since). Content disappears while animating and a lot of animations does not work at all.

I have tried to just do a simple scale, but even that doesn't work ...

http://nordjyske.it/chrome-bug/

(on my browser, the div disappears, and reappears halfway through the animation. Depending on other content on the page, it sometimes disappears completely throughout the duration of the animation...)

Using -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; on the item or parents seems to make things even worse :(

---

Updated: I tested using the latest Chrome Canary build and here the animation works. Look at the videos below:

Chrome 14: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvhGcmAaLhU

Comment: When testing in Safari, everything works as usual.

Comment: Same build of Chrome on Mac, the animation works fine. Is your windows & graphics driver up to date?

Comment: I just tested on another PC where it also works fine. I did not change or update my graphic drivers and win7 is up to date. It's strange. - Update: It works for me in Chrome 16 (canary) see link above

Comment: Chrome 16 (canary): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O74H1m-aGNM

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what this issue, but it sounds GPU related (e.g. `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` makes things worse). You should test your pages out in the latest version
of Chrome (either dev channel or preferably Chrome Canary). If they're reproducible, than it's likely a bug. Please file one at crbug.com/new

Comment: It works when I run the test using Chrome 16 (canary): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O74H1m-aGNM

Strange. Must be a Chrome 14 bug?